# Infinite number of regular exressions for a given language

Tags: infinity, regular-language, regular-expressions

Took a Theory of Computation exam where one of the questions was :

Is there an infinite amount of regular expressions for the language $L=\{aa,bb\}$ ?

The proof requested was just an **informal** one.

My intuition was that if a set is countably infinite then it is infinite itself.

Then I thought that the following regular expressions are different :

- $(aa)\ \cup \ (bb)$
- $(aa)\ \cup \ (bb) \ \cup \ \emptyset$
- $(aa)\ \cup \ (bb) \ \cup \ \emptyset \ \cup \ \emptyset$
- $\dots$

So I can define a set of them that can be countably infinite.

To be clear I was taught some of the **very basics** of set theory so bare with me.

My questions are :

- Are the regular expressions mentioned above different from one another?
- Is a countably infinite set infinite itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "a regular expression for a language"? A regular expression defining the language? A regular expression built with symbols for the language? Also, what do you mean by the unione of expressions?

Comment: @AndreaMarino a regular expression describes a regular language and $\{aa, bb\}$ is a regular one. As explained here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right. You could also write $aa$ as $a\varepsilon a$, $a\varepsilon \varepsilon a$, etc., to get another countable set of regular expressions.